# Does OTC Markets offer options

Tags: stocks, options

I am just curious whether OTC Markets offer options. For example, I just searched OTCMKTS: SIUIF, Semiconductor Manufacturing Int'l. It seems that this stock does not have options to trade. Is this a restriction placed by OTC Markets? Thanks

Comment: Similar: [Are there stock options on OTC stocks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/127667)

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks